# Unit test for void method with Task in it

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

So I have a command which uses a service. The service has an async method and in its continuations some other actions are done.

```
public override void Execute(object parameter)
{
   // some action

    _someService.LoadSomeDataAsync()
        .Then(loadedData =>
        {
            _dataHandler.DataSource.AddRange(loadedData);
        })
        .Then((() =>
        {
           // some other action
        }))
        .Finally(() =>
        {
           _dataHandler.DataSource.NotifyView();
        });
}
```

My question is how to unit test it? I could change it to async/await if it wouldn't be inserted into a command and then It would be easily testable. Or if I only want to test the `LoadSomeDataAsync()` but I need to know if the actions in the continuations are executed as well.

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand and reproduce your problem.

Comment: This code is quite sad because there is no guarantee that `Then` is even ever going to be called, as the call is not awaited (i imagine VS generates a warning for you there).

That said, you could use Microsoft Fakes or Pose (https://github.com/tonerdo/pose) to make it run synchronously by testing `LoadSomeDataAsync()` separately and overriding it in the test where you test the `Then` actions.